# Tic-Tac-Toe AI: How to Make the Tree?

Tags: c++, tree, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I'm having a huge block trying to understand "trees" while making a Tic-Tac-Toe bot.  I understand the concept, but I can't figure out to implement them.

Can someone show me an example of how a tree should be generated for such a case? Or a good tutorial on generating trees? I guess the hard part is generating partial trees. I know how to implement generating a whole tree, but not parts of it.

Comment: What sort of tree? A Minimax tree?

Comment: Any tree that stores the state for the next possible move. A minimax tree would work, I'm just looking to see how a "tree" is filled/navigated/etc. I don't have any experience working with trees

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Imagine that at any point in a tic-tac-toe board, every single possible move is a branch.  The current state of the board is the root.  One move is a branch.  Now pretend (one at a time), that each branch becomes the current state.  Each possible move becomes a new branch.  The leaf of the tree is when the last move is made and the board is full.

The reason you need to have a tree, is that once it is built, you need to figure out which branch has the most leaves that are 'WIN' scenarios.  You build the branch of all possible outcomes, add up the total number of WINs, and then make the move that has the chance to end up with the most wins.

Make the tree something like this:

```
class Node {
public:
   std::list< Node > m_branches;
   BoardState m_board;
   int m_winCount;
}

std::list< Node > tree;
```

Now, you iterate through the list of branches in the tree, and for each branch, iterate through its branches.  This can be done with a recursive function:

```
int recursiveTreeWalk( std::list< Node >& partialTree)
{

   for each branch in tree
       if node has no branches
           calculate win 1/0;
       else
           recursiveTreeWalk( branch );

   partialTree.m_winCount = sum of branch wins;
}

// initial call
recursiveTreeWalk( tree )
```

Very pseudo-code.

Comment: ... that being said, it's not really AI at this point, but a rigorous determination of all possible outcomes, and taking the exactly appropriate risk.

Comment: Right, thanks that explanation helped, but the main trouble I'm having is implementing this. I understand the concept fully, but generating the tree and navigating it is stumping me. I'm looking for some source code that could help me, or even a tutorial. My brain needs to see one example before I understand a concept in code.

Comment: To make it more AI like you could use a max depth to limit the look ahead.  Or a timer to limit the amount of time that would be spent on look ahead - though on TTT the calculation of a complete tree would be done in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to keep a tree in memory. You simply need to implement a recursive function that works something like:

```
Move getBestMove(Board state, boolean myTurn)
```

Then you simply recurse until you've reached a winning, losing or draw-state.

The call-stack would over time look like a tree if you drew it on paper. You should return the move that leads to a node at which the opponent (definitely / most likely) looses (even though he also plays using getBestMove)

For a state-space as little as tic-tac-toe however, you could simply do a full look-up-table with the best moves! :-)

Comment: I guess this is what I didn't understand. I thought an actual tree structure was being created in memory. This is how I implemented the bot as of now, using a recursive function without trees.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this codeproject article interesting :

[Solve Tic Tac Toe with the MiniMax algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/TicTacToeByMinMax.aspx)

It's in C#, but it won't be any problem to adapt it in C++.

This article was also a good read for me when I tried to implement my first Tic-Tac-Toe game in C++ :

[Minimax Explained](https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/minimax)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the tree in memory (which is not necessary), perhaps an algorithm like the following could be used (pseudo-code):

```
GenTree(State s):
  T <- empty tree  // T is a tree of States
  SetRoot(T, s)

  ForEach (s' in Successors(s)):
    AddChild(T, GenTree(s'))

  return T

// Call it
GenTree(currentMove)
```

where

```
Successors(s)  // returns a list of successor states of s
AddChild(p, n)  // adds n to the list of p's children
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the Tic Tac Toe game is probably the simplest problem to solve in terms of AI 
and search space.

The key is to approach the problem with [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), [Iterative deepening Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) and [Alpha-beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) algorithms.

Here's my [implementation](https://github.com/dmumladze/TicTacToe) of the game in Python, which is only ~200 lines of code and has the capability to play a game as `Human vs. Human`, `Human vs. Computer`, and `Computer vs. Computer`. It also keeps the statistics on depths and number of nodes reached/pruned leading up to the best move.

I highly recommend `edX.org` Artificial Intelligence [course](https://www.edx.org/course/artificial-intelligence-ai-columbiax-csmm-101x-0), which gives the the fundamental knowledge on current AI topics and solutions.